# Center login button in asp.net login form

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I :

1. Center the login button in the form
2. Change the text of Log In 
   (Check below image)

My current code is :

`<asp:Login CssClass="loginbox" id="Login1"  DisplayRememberMe="False" runat="server"
BackColor="#F7F6F3" BorderColor="#E6E2D8" BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333" Height="255px" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" Width="541px">
<CheckBoxStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
<InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
<LoginButtonStyle  BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" 
Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284775" />
<TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
<TitleTextStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:Login>`

[image: form]

Answer (score 1):

```
<span class="button">
    <button type="button">Click me!</button>
</span>
```

and this CSS:

```
.button {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The align attribute specifies the horizontal alignment of the content inside a  element.

```
<div align="center">
      <asp:Button ID="MyButton"  runat="server" />
</div>
```

The  align attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

CSS syntax: `<div style="text-align:center">`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the HTML that gets generated for the login control you will notice that the "Log In" button is contained inside a `<td align="right">` element:

[image: Login control HTML]

Now you know what's making the button right aligned.To make it centered you can write a tiny bit of jQuery to find the `<td>` in question and change the alignment from `right` to `center`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var td = $('input[value="Log In"]').parent();
        alert($(td).html());
        $(td).attr("align", "center");

    });
</script>
```